# Elasticsearch - how to check for key exist script query parameters?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Is there any way to return null if there is no corresponding value?

example) Since params do not have a field4 value, I want the null value to be returned to the syn variable.

```
"aggs": {
    "countries": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "params": {
            "field1": "country",
            "field2": "test",
            "field3": "test"
          },
          "inline": "def syn = field4; if (syn == null) doc[country].value;"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Currently, errors always occur if there is no corresponding value.

```
"caused_by": {
   "type": "missing_property_exception",
   "reason": "No such property: field1 for class: e5ce2464b456f9c0fa360269abc927e65998ecf7"
}
```

I am using groovy and elasticsearch version 2.2

I can't use Python or JavaScript, which requires additional plug-ins to be installed.

How can I get a null value without causing an error if there is no value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [boolean value called `empty`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields) that indicates you whether the document has such a field or not.

So you should do it this way

```
      "inline": "def syn = field4 ?: 'dummy'; return (doc[syn].empty) ? null : doc[syn].value;"
```

**UPDATE:** To detect a missing parameter variable in Groovy is trivial if we know the script class name. But since the script class is created dynamically (e.g. `e5ce2464b456f9c0fa360269abc927e65998ecf7`), it makes the process not trivial at all. One way to circumvent this is to add a try/catch block around your code, so that the code can fail but at least we can catch it, basically like this:

```
      "inline": "try { def syn = field4; return (doc[syn].empty) ? null : doc[syn].value; } catch (e) { return null } "
```

However, ES [introduced](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/release-notes-2.2.0.html) some security hardening and class whitelisting for scripting in 2.2. One way to achieve this is to [whitelist](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16464#issuecomment-180207058) a few Exception classes in your `.java.policy` file, like this:

```
grant {
  permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.lang.Throwable";
  permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.lang.Exception";
  permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "groovy.lang.GroovyException";
};
```

Comment: Same Error Occured `def syn = field4;` There seems to be an error in that part before checking the importy.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Let me update my answer

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you try again? Sorry I cannot test it, because I can't install 2.2 anymore, too old.

Comment: not work same error occured

Comment: Ok, I did some more research and updated my answer. Please give it a try

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Fantastic, glad we nailed it!